# Is it possible to have a method act like a property in a javascript class?

Tags: javascript

Take the following piece of javascript that is trying to implement a class:

```
function aClass(){
  this.prop1 = this.getProp1();
}

aClass.prototype.getProp1 = function(){
  // do some stuff
  return result;
}
```

I can then use it like so:

```
var obj = new aClass();
alert(obj.prop1);
```

What I now want to do is this:

```
obj.prop1 = "some value";
```

This, of course overrides prop1, and I can no longer retrieve the generated result from the getProp1 function.

So in short, is it possible to create a property that allows read and write, but instead calls a function in both cases for, say, validation purposes?

I'm happy for a completely different approach to what I have here as long as I get the desired effect.

It needs to work with older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define getters and setters for object properties; see [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters). The syntax is going to be identical to getting or setting a property, but code will run instead of a dumb value change.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hFy4/).

Compatibility constraint: will not work in IE < 9.

Comment: jquery is not an option, do you have an example that doesn't use jquery.  I tried to modify your live example and remove the jquery bits from it, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Graham: My example uses jQuery just to associate the buttons and the input field with the property. You can totally remove it and just access the property straight up.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work in the end, but unfortunately it doesn't work in older browsers.

Comment: @Graham: In older browsers this is simply not doable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not limited by some older JS implementation, you can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).